# SwiftUI - Set back sheet to be full screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, dictionary, swiftui

I'm working on an app on SwiftUI.

The main page ressemble Apple Map's app as there's a sheet that's always there, and you can lower it up or down.

My issue is, when you lower it up, the back sheet (where there is a map) kinda fades away instead of staying there in full screen. (like it does in Apple Map's app)

[image]

My question is very simple: how do I prevent this from happening, and keep the back sheet to full screen size? (so it is like Apple Map's app)

Comment: SwiftUI doesn’t have the ability yet. UIKit has a setting with their adaptive presentation controller. I don’t remember which it is off the top of my head but it is a Bool if I remember correctly.

Comment: Is it possible, if I find this boolean, to kinda "merge" UIKit and SwiftUI to use make it possible?

Comment: Not from SwiftUI you would have to interface between them as required when it was first introduced in iOS 15?

Comment: Any information on how to make said interface?

Comment: Look at old posts about "Half Model", "Half Sheet" for SwiftUI, that is all that was available back then, you can use the new detents if you adapt but I know there are a few posts out there.